# How can I log members who joined a server using a bot's invite link in Python's discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I would like to ask how can I log when someone use bot's invite link to join server. For some reason it log all joins, can you help me please?

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    invite = await get_existing_never_ending_invite(member.guild)
    if invite and member.guild.id == invite.guild.id:
        log_channel_id = 1103749918079852676
        log_channel = bot.get_channel(log_channel_id)
        if log_channel is not None:
            embed = discord.Embed(description = f"<:3199blurplejoin:1109799576375918722> **{member.display_name}** just joined **{member.guild.name}**", color=discord.Color(int("313338", 16)))
            await log_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Logging only joins of members that used bot's invite to join server

```
async def get_existing_never_ending_invite(guild):
invites = await guild.invites()
for invite in invites:
    if invite.max_age == 0 and invite.max_uses == 0 and invite.inviter == guild.me:
        return invite
return None
```

Comment: it would be very helpful if you also post the code of the get_existing_never_ending_invite function ...

Comment: And make sure the code runs without errors. This one has at least an indentation error.

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. You need to find out which invitation the user used to join the server.
[This article](https://medium.com/@tonite/finding-the-invite-code-a-user-used-to-join-your-discord-server-using-discord-py-5e3734b8f21f) shows how find out which invite a member used when joining the server.